# Laravel: How to add 1 day to validation before rule

Tags: php, laravel

How do I make the validation rule `before:end_date` +1 day? I.E. I want to make the rule before or including the end date. I know that the date is passed to the php strtotime function which takes '+1 days' as an argument but I can't get it to work.

```
protected $fillable = array('name','start_date', 'end_date', 'registration_start', 'registration_end');

public static $rules = array(
    'registration_end' => 'required|date|before:end_date + 1 days'
);
```

Comment: Why not you `$date = $end_date + 1;` and then `'registration_end' => 'required|date|before:$date'` ?

Comment: I don't think I can edit `end_date` as a variable beforehand because it gets evaluated at runtime from a database query or form input search and is passed into the `strtotime` function. I am not sure but I think that's what happens.

Comment: What is the format or `end_date`  ?

Comment: Datetime format like so "2008-6-30". It is a field in my database and also my input form.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about you can edit the `end_date`. You should do this to add a day before you pass to your rule.

```
$end_date = '<your date> +1 day';
```

Note : Replace `<your date>` with your original date ('Y-m-d' or 'Y/m/d' format works)

Then you shall pass it to the rule as usual

```
public static $rules = array(
    'registration_end' => 'required|date|before:'.$end_date
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have to do that in the area of code that queries the form for the actual value in `end_date`. Right now my $rules are in the model definition. Will try it on Monday.

Comment: I shortened the code to `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data["end_date"] . "+1 day"));`

Comment: That's great,, You shall edit my answer accordingly. And that works for you ?

Comment: A ':' is missing after the ```before```

Comment: Since a one character update (':') wasn't allowed I shortened the code a bit more (tested on PHP 5.2). Hope you like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use request key : 
`'registration_end' => 'required|date|before:end_date'` if you want `end_date` to precede `registration_end`.   
 For specific time add time text `before:end_date +1 day`.